# Spring Batch next run start fom last read page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch to move data from two different databases and I would like that at every run the item reader job will start from the latest page (I'm using the JpaPagingItemReader).

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the processed indicator flag pattern, you can configure your queries to only pick up items that have not been processed.  You can read more about this pattern in the Spring Batch documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#process-indicator